# (HTML5) Can't load my image

Tags: html, image

For some reason, despite using the right syntax(to my knowledge) and having the image file in the same folder as my HTML document, when I load the document, the image I programmed to load does not appear on the page. What could be the issue here?

Here, my HTML file is clearly in the same folder as my image..

https://gyazo.com/ac35ed711716d9e8c5b34123f80d71d1

And here is my code (this is for `q3.html`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question Three</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <h1>Dominos Pizza order form</h1>
            <img src=“dominos.png” alt=“Dominos logo” width=“100” height=“50”>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am running this on a Macbook Pro, using TextEdit as my editing tool. Here is what my page looks like after I open the document:

https://gyazo.com/0a527e90897d082b1f722c3293ad34d0

Comment: try this `<img src="dominos.png" alt="Dominos logo" width="100" height="50">`

Comment: Yeah, it's likely the typographic quotes causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice `“` in your `<img>`. It is not the actual quotes. Thus replace `“` with `"`.

Thus the new HTML would be as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question Three</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <h1>Dominos Pizza order form</h1>
            <img src="dominos.png" alt="Dominos logo" width="100" height="50">
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. " and “ are different characters completely (albeit they look the similar)

Comment: Yes.. :D ... Happy coding.. :)

Comment: However what I don't understand is how textedit makes all text plain, yet that one character is not useful..

Comment: Sorry..i dont know..havent used textedit so far.. :(